# Is It Safe to Kill splwow64.exe?

Tags: printing, windows-server-2008-r2

#### Background

I have a server running Windows Server 2008 R2 on which the `splwow64.exe` process appears to have a memory leak.

I understand that this process allows 32-bit applications to communicate with 64-bit printer drivers on a 64-bit system, and that the process should terminate when the application is finished communicating with the printer, i.e. when the print job has completed.

After researching the issue, I have applied [this Microsoft hotfix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2815716/splwow64-exe-process-doesn-t-end-after-a-print-job-finishes-in-the-64) (2815716) unfortunately to no avail.

---

#### My question is this:

Would it be a safe and wise move to schedule a task to automatically terminate this process at the end of the day, when confident that all print jobs have completed?

---

#### Footnote

*I realise that this behaviour indicates an underlying issue with a particular printer driver installed on the system, however, the server is running a set of ancient printers whose drivers cannot be updated.*

---

Your time & advice is very much appreciated.

Comment: Change the startup type of "Printer Spooler" service to "manual". In my opinion, it is safe to stop that service but not safe to forcefully kill that service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appear to have found a solution to this issue:

---

I compared the timing of the spikes in RAM usage against the jobs sent to various print queues and narrowed the issue down to a set of HP Laserjet printers which were configured to use a `PCL6` driver.

Changing the driver to the `PCL5 HP Universal Printer Driver` seems to have solved the problem.

The `splwow64.exe` process now consumes between 250KB-1MB RAM when the print job is sent, and this RAM is then subsequently released successfully by the process (previously the process was consuming 65MB-500MB RAM per print job, which wasn't then being released).

---

My thanks to everyone who read my question and contributed to this thread.

Answer (score 2):

It would be a way better idea to have a scheduled task to restart the service every night/morning.

```
net stop spooler
net start spooler
```

That process is part of the service and you don't want to force it.

Comment: Unfortunately restarting the Print Spooler service doesn't appear to relinquish the memory consumed by the splwow64.exe process...

Comment: When you stop the spooler service, the process should end. Can you verify if it does?

Comment: I can confirm that it does **not** end the `splwow64.exe` process.

Comment: I know you said you applied the above hotfix. Have you tried setting the timeout in the same article?

Comment: Yes, I tried adding the `DWORD` value as instructed by the hotfix article and restarted, also to no avail. However, I believe I have now found a solution which I have posted as an answer so that others may benefit. Thank you for all your help with this Devon Quick.